# Open Popup automatically if Anchor is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

I have an image gallery. When the page first loads, it uses Ajax to grab some images and also has a "Load More" button. [This is working (Plunker)](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ooSZTpsgHmQDtLB9?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

However, my problem is that I want to automatically load and open the popup of an image if its id is present the URL, like "http://localhost/test_json/new/#cd0".

Here is the code I used.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    // adding click event listener to the button
    $('#myButton1').on('click', function() {
        // make the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"data_hidden.xml",
            dataType:"xml",
            success:localHoliday
        });
    });    
});
   function localHoliday(xml){

    xml = $(xml).children();

    let i = 0;
    let total = $(xml).children().length;
    $("#rest_localHoliday").empty();
    $("#rest_localHoliday2").empty();
    $(xml).children().each(function (idx,index,item) {


        let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
        let nextIdx = idx + 1;
        let prevIdx = idx - 1;
        //to make cyclic
        nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
        prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total -1) : prevIdx;

        let image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image").text() + ')"' + '" />';
        let image2 = '<div><img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" width="100%" alt="' + '" />' + '</div>';
        let head = '<div>' + $(this).find("head").text() + '</div>';


        let html = `<div class="col-sm-4 random" id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail randomdiv3" id="border" >
                    <a href="#${tag + idx}" id="openModalBtn">
                            <div>${image}</div>
                            <h5>${head}</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>`;
        let popup = `<div id="${tag + idx}" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">

                <a href="#${tag + prevIdx}" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
                <a href="#${tag + nextIdx}" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
                    <h6>${head}</h6>
                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <div>${image2}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        i++;


        if(i <= 3)    {
            $("#xmldata_hidden2").append(html);
            $("#xmldata_hiddenall").append(html);
        }
        else{            
            $("#xmldata_hidden").append(html);
        }

        $("#popup2").append(popup);
    });

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash != ""){
        $("a[href='"+hash+"']").find("h5").click();
    }
    $("a[id='openModalBtn']").click(function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });
}
```

Comment: When is the event share popup url shows?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to understand your question but I do not understand what the problem is. Please expand your problem description in the first paragraph. What is a "hidden section thumbnail"? Where do you click on it? Where is the hash URL you are trying to copy? What should it look like? What do you mean about copying the URL - how? I looked at your plunkr and just couldn't see the problem you are trying to describe. Please clarify.

Comment: Yeah i was blur as well.

Comment: When click on the image, the popup is open. Also it show a url like "http://localhost/test_json/new/#cd0". I need to share that url. Using that url,  need to open the popup box directly. Currently I can share the urls of first section popups. But, Can't share the urls of hidden section popups. Please check the plunker project. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: It seems like if there's `#cd0` in the url, open the popup automatically.

Comment: @Chris Happy I can't direct open '#cd3'

Comment: It's opening directly. Please check this video.
https://vimeo.com/299150731

Comment: @SoravGarg please copy URL  http://localhost/Project/#cd3 and try to open it in another tab

Comment: OK, I'll check.

Comment: Yes, It's not showing because #cd3 images load on run time after click on view all button. but when i hit #cd3 url in browser directly, then in this case #cd3 link not found in HTML, It's show's in HTML after click on View All.

Comment: If #cd3 present in URL then you want to automatic click on view all ? or will manage manully ? bcz if you want manually then It will automatic open after click on view all

Comment: @SoravGarg Yes. But I don't know how to automatic click on view all button, If the element is present

Comment: I have added code, Please check it and let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183170/discussion-between-sorav-garg-and-user2893).

Comment: @Sorav Garg It is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code for automated click, I hope it will solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <title>XML Parse</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/idss.ico" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Site CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"data.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:xmlParser2
    });
   });
   function xmlParser2(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();
    let i = 0;
    let total = $(xml).children().length;
    $(xml).children().each(function (idx,index,item) {

        let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
        let nextIdx = idx + 1;
        let prevIdx = idx - 1;
        //to make cyclic
        nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
        prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total -1) : prevIdx;

        let expireArray = $(this).attr('expires').split('/');
        const expireDate = `${expireArray[2]}${expireArray[1]}${expireArray[0]}`;
        const now = new Date(),
            nowDate = `${now.getFullYear()}${(now.getMonth()+1) <12 ? '0'+(now.getMonth()+1): (now.getMonth()+1)}${now.getDate()}`;

        if (nowDate > expireDate) {            
            return (idx + 1) ; 
        }

        let image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image").text() + ')"' + '" />';
        let image2 = '<div><img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" width="100%" alt="' + '" />' + '</div>';
        let head = '<div>' + $(this).find("head").text() + '</div>';



        let html = `<div class="col-sm-4 random reveal" id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail randomdiv3">
                    <a href="#${tag + idx}" id="openModalBtn">
                            <div>${image}</div>
                            <h5>${head}</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>`;
        let popup = `<div id="${tag + idx}" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">

                <a href="#${tag + prevIdx}" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
                <a href="#${tag + nextIdx}" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
                    <h6>${head}</h6>
                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <div>${image2}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

i++;


        if(i <= 3)    {
            $("#xmldata").append(html);
            $("#xmldata_hiddenall").append(html);
        }
        else{            
            $("#xmldata2").append(html);
        }

        $("#popup").append(popup);
    });

function loadData(url, selector) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: "xml"
            });
        }

if(!loadData("data_hidden.xml")){
            $('.next').on('click', function() {
            // make the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"data_hidden.xml",
                dataType:"xml",
                success:localHoliday
            });
        });
 }

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash != ""){
        $('#myButton1').click();
        $("a[href='"+hash+"']").find("h5").click();
    }
    $("a[id='openModalBtn']").click(function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });


}
</script>

<!--**********End Local Holiday*************-->

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    // adding click event listener to the button
    $('#myButton1').on('click', function() {
        // make the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"data_hidden.xml",
            dataType:"xml",
            success:localHoliday
        });
    });    
});
   function localHoliday(xml){
   /* var items = $(xml).children().children();
    items.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });*/

    xml = $(xml).children();

    let i = 0;
    let total = $(xml).children().length;
    $("#rest_localHoliday").empty();
    $("#rest_localHoliday2").empty();

    $(xml).children().each(function (idx,index,item) {

    let expireArray = $(this).attr('expires').split('/');
        const expireDate = `${expireArray[2]}${expireArray[1]}${expireArray[0]}`;
        const now = new Date(),
            nowDate = `${now.getFullYear()}${(now.getMonth()+1) <12 ? '0'+(now.getMonth()+1): (now.getMonth()+1)}${now.getDate()}`;

        if (nowDate > expireDate) {
            return;
        }

        let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
        let nextIdx = idx + 1;
        let prevIdx = idx - 1;
        //to make cyclic
        nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
        prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total -1) : prevIdx;

        let image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image").text() + ')"' + '" />';
        let image2 = '<div><img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" width="100%" alt="' + '" />' + '</div>';
        let head = '<div>' + $(this).find("head").text() + '</div>';


        let html = `<div class="col-sm-4 random" id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail randomdiv3" id="border" >
                    <a href="#${tag + idx}" id="openModalBtn">
                            <div>${image}</div>
                            <h5>${head}</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>`;
        let popup = `<div id="${tag + idx}" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">

                <a href="#${tag + prevIdx}" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
                <a href="#${tag + nextIdx}" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
                    <h6>${head}</h6>
                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <div>${image2}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        i++;


        if(i <= 3)    {
            $("#xmldata_hidden2").append(html);
            $("#xmldata_hiddenall").append(html);
        }
        else{            
            $("#xmldata_hidden").append(html);
        }

        $("#popup2").append(popup);
    });

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash != ""){
        $("a[href='"+hash+"']").find("h5").click();
    }
    $("a[id='openModalBtn']").click(function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


        <div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>
        <div class="row" id="xmldata2" style="display: none;"></div>

        <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="button" value="View All" id="myButton1" class="reveal" style="float: right;"  onclick="toggler('toggle_container');">

                        <div id="toggle_container" class='hide'>
                        <div class="block">
                          <div class="row" id="xmldata_hidden2" style="display: none;"></div>
                           <div class="row" id="xmldata_hidden"></div>

                        </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            </section>
            <div id="popup2"></div>
        <section id="popup"></section>


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#myButton1').click(function () {
                                var self = this;
                                change(self);
                            });

                            function change(el) {
                                if (el.value === "View All")
                                    el.value = "Hide All";
                                else
                                    el.value = "View All";
                            }

                            function toggler(divId) {
                                $("#" + divId).toggleClass("hide");

                            }


                            function directLinkModal(hash) {
                                $(hash).modal('show');
                            }

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```